# How to save session storage item to variable

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I need to save some items from local storage with c# (via js, because seems like there is no solution with 'pure' c#). I've tried this (sorry for code convention, I've been doing it in a hurry):

```
public string token;

string storageToken = "localStorage.getItem('token')";

token = (string)js.ExecuteScript(storageToken);`
```

When I run this, it gets an empty string for these elements. My aim is to get local storage elements, save them to variables and use them with in another method:

```
string tokenSetItemScript = $"localStorage.setItem('token','{token}')";

js.ExecuteScript(tokenSetItemScript);
```

Comment: You should include the complete code.  I don't think you'll be able to get those values if you are not currently at the domain that set them.  There's no way to tell what domain you are on with the above code.  You probably also need a return statement in your JS, but Alex's answer below seems a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript you can set an item or get an item from local storage

```
public static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    public static void SetItemToLocalStorage(this IWebDriver driver, string key, string value)
    {
        var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript("localStorage.setItem(arguments[0],arguments[1])", key, value);
    }

    public static string GetItemFromLocalStorage(this IWebDriver driver, string key)
    {
        var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        return (string)js.ExecuteScript($"return window.localStorage.getItem('{key}')");
    }
}
```

and then use these extension methods like:

```
driver.SetItemToLocalStorage("token", "your-token");
string token = driver.GetItemFromLocalStorage("token")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this (Java example but C# should be pretty similar):

```
LocalStorage local = ((WebStorage) driver).getLocalStorage();
```

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent WebStorage interface (or class) for c# anymore. I found this https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_WebStorage.htm
but as far as I know it is missing from the latest selenium versions.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it's not working in this way with c#